# $.ajax async:false trouble

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I know it looks like a duplicate question and believe me, I read all of them and tried everything, but I can't get this to work (JQuery 1.11.0):

```
function gip(){
var ccode;
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?',
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.country_code);
        ccode = data.country_code;
        },
    error: function(error) {
        alert(error)
        return '';
        }
    });
alert(ccode);
return ccode;
}
```

No matter what I do, `alert(ccode)` fires before `alert(data.country_code)` so my return value is undefined. Unfortunately my knowledge is limited, and I can't see how I can do what I need in asynchronous mode. I simply need to return `data.country_code`.

Comment: The simple answer is, *never* use `async:false`.  Don't wait for asynchronous operations to complete, use the response handlers they provide to respond to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, since you are using jsonp, you can't do anything :(

As of version 1.8, `async:false` is no longer supported

You'll need to wait for `success` handler to get whatever value you are looking for.

Comment: `async: false` is supported in 1.11 and 2.x and is NOT deprecated yet. Even if he downgraded to 1.5, he wouldn't be able to send a synchronous jsonp request because it's jsonp, not because the library doesn't support it. It simply isn't possible due to how a jsonp request works.

Comment: What was deprecated in 1.8 was the use of .done() .fail() and .always() with synchronous requests.

Comment: I really didn't see `jsonp`.

Comment: @KevinB, I thought you would argue, that I _stole_ your answer.

Comment: No, I care more that the answers available are correct. My answer is common knowledge

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49972/discussion-between-amit-joki-and-kevin-b)

Comment: Thanks. So what's the right way to deal with this, as I really need the value to continue with the rest of the script?

Comment: Use callbacks. it's the only way.

Comment: Yes, but how? Do I have to use something like a while loop on the other side to wait for the answer? Or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: @chris, `success:function(){}` is a callback.

Comment: Yes, I know that :). But what's next?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to send a synchronous jsonp request.

JSONP requests are done by appending a `<script>` tag to the `<head>` tag. Since it isn't possible to force a `<script>` tag to load synchronously after the DOM is ready, it isn't possible to force a jQuery jsonp request to be synchronous.

Comment: hmm... if you created an iframe with a document and added the script tag to it before it gets parsed, would it load that script synchronously? Still wouldn't solve the OP's issue, but it would technically cause a *synchronous* jsonp request to happen.